# C# List.Contains does return true when it should

Tags: c#, linq

So I am creating a little Noughts and Crosses app (Tic tac toe for my American friends) just to practice a little and I've stumbled across an issue.

I have 3 items in a `List<PlayerPositons>` and I'm trying to look for a certain position. However when I use the LINQ method `Contains` it does not return true when looking for a position which I know for certain is there.

Here is the code:

```
private void CheckIfWinner(object sender, PlayerClickedOnBoardEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CurrentPositions != null) {
        var potentialWinnersPositions = e.CurrentPositions.GroupBy(r => r.Player).Where(r => r.Count() >= 3);

        foreach (var item in potentialWinnersPositions) {
            var verticalGrouping = item.Where(r => r.Player == item.Key).GroupBy(r => r.VerticalPosition);
            //If there are three vertically then there must be a winner
            foreach (var vert in verticalGrouping) {
                if (vert.Select(r => r.VerticalPosition).Count() == 3) {
                    _view.WinnerMessage = $"Congratulations player {item.Key}. You won!";
                    return;
                }
            }

            var horizontalGrouping = item.Where(r => r.Player == item.Key).GroupBy(r => r.HorizontalPositon);
            //If there are three hoirzontally then there must be a winner
            foreach (var horiz in horizontalGrouping) {
                if (horiz.Select(r => r.HorizontalPositon).Count() == 3) {
                    _view.WinnerMessage = $"Congratulations player {item.Key}. You won!";
                    return;
                }
            }

            //If item contains the center button then there is a possibility of a winner 
            //Happens here
            if (item.Select(r => r).Contains(new Models.PlayerPosition(item.Key, Models.Position._verticalPosition.Middle, Models.Position._horizontalPosition.Middle))) {
                if (item.Where(r => r.VerticalPosition == Models.Position._verticalPosition.Top) != null && item.Where(r => r.VerticalPosition == Models.Position._verticalPosition.Bottom) != null) {
                    _view.WinnerMessage = $"Congratulations player {item.Key}. You won!";
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I am trying to look for the center block in the square and item contains these items:

```
PositionCollection positions = new PositionCollection() {
    new PlayerPosition('x', Position._verticalPosition.Top, Position._horizontalPosition.Left),
    new PlayerPosition('o', Position._verticalPosition.Middle, Position._horizontalPosition.Left),
    new PlayerPosition('x', Position._verticalPosition.Middle, Position._horizontalPosition.Middle),
    new PlayerPosition('o', Position._verticalPosition.Middle, Position._horizontalPosition.Right),
    new PlayerPosition('x', Position._verticalPosition.Bottom, Position._horizontalPosition.Right),
};
```

Why is `Contains` returning false?

Edit - PlayerPosition class:

```
public class PlayerPosition : IEquatable<PlayerPosition>{
    public enum _verticalPosition { Top, Middle, Bottom };
    public enum _horizontalPosition { Left, Middle, Right };
    public PlayerPosition(char player, _verticalPosition vert, _horizontalPosition horiz) {
        if (player != 'x' && player != 'o') {
            throw new ArgumentException("Player must be either x or o.");
        }
        Player = player;
        VerticalPosition = vert;
        HorizontalPositon = horiz;
    }

    public char Player { get; set; }
    public _verticalPosition VerticalPosition { get; set; }
    public _horizontalPosition HorizontalPositon { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        PlayerPosition pos = (PlayerPosition)obj;
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (pos.HorizontalPositon == HorizontalPositon && pos.VerticalPosition == VerticalPosition
                && pos.Player == Player) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(PlayerPosition other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (other.HorizontalPositon == HorizontalPositon && other.VerticalPosition == VerticalPosition
                && other.Player == Player) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(PlayerPosition a, PlayerPosition b) {
        return Equals(a, b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(PlayerPosition a, PlayerPosition b) {
        return !Equals(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the documentation says so *This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable<T>.Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).*

Comment: Right so it's not working because they're both reference types ?

Comment: btw, this looks like horrible code, since this is a practice app, try and simplify it and untangle it

Comment: It is not working, because you did not tell the program what you expect as equal

Comment: @KeithNicholas I know it's not great. I wanted to get it working first. I could just store a list of winning positions and check against that but im not a fan as it would be hard coded. Although its not like the rules of the game are going to change any time soon

Comment: Override PlayerPosition Equals and GetHashcode methods to define equality

Comment: @SirRufo I've just done that but Contains still wouldn't use my implementation

Comment: Many games, once in software, get their rules changed....  like turning it into a 4x4 tictactoe.... making it a 3 player game....  or many other things

Comment: @Andrew Add the definition for PlayerPosition with the not working Equals method. BTW overriding Equals is **not** enough. GetHashcode has to be overridden either

Comment: @KeithNicholas True but I'm just going for the basic implementation first

Comment: @SirRufo I have gotten it to work with my Equals method. However the contains method still uses the default Equals method. I just don't want to add yet another foreach in the code to use my Equals method instead

Comment: There is no need for that if you override **both** methods (Equals, GetHashcode)

Comment: And please add the **complete** PlayerPosition class definition.

Comment: @SirRufo I think you have given me enough to go on. I'm going to watch a pluralsight video on overriding GetHashCode. Please check my edit for what I have up to press

Comment: @SirRufo I have just implemented GetHashCode and my application now works with contains. I now understand why, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I understand, LINQ `Contains` uses the default object `Equals` method to calculate whether the values are equal.

In my instance they did not equal one another according to the Equals operator, so I have overrided both the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method. The `Contains` method now uses these to calculate whether they are equal.

Shout out to Sir Rufo for helping me.

```
public class PlayerPosition {
        public enum _verticalPosition { Top, Middle, Bottom };
        public enum _horizontalPosition { Left, Middle, Right };

        public PlayerPosition(char player, _verticalPosition vert, _horizontalPosition horiz) {
            if (player != 'x' && player != 'o') {
                throw new ArgumentException("Player must be either x or o.");
            }
            Player = player;
            VerticalPosition = vert;
            HorizontalPositon = horiz;
        }

        public char Player { get; set; }
        public _verticalPosition VerticalPosition { get; set; }
        public _horizontalPosition HorizontalPositon { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            PlayerPosition pos = (PlayerPosition)obj;
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (pos.HorizontalPositon == HorizontalPositon && pos.VerticalPosition == VerticalPosition
                    && pos.Player == Player) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return Player.GetHashCode() ^ HorizontalPositon.GetHashCode() ^ VerticalPosition.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator ==(PlayerPosition a, PlayerPosition b) {
            return Equals(a, b);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(PlayerPosition a, PlayerPosition b) {
            return !Equals(a, b);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Contains checks `.Equals()` for comparison of references. Maybe what you need is `==` check for the actual coordinates.
So instead of:

```
.Contains(new Models.PlayerPosition(item.Key, Models.Position._verticalPosition.Middle, Models.Position._horizontalPosition.Middle))
```

try something like:

```
.Any(r => r.VerticalPosition == Models.Position._verticalPosition.Middle &&  r.HorizontalPosition == Models.Position._horizontalPosition.Middle))
```

Comment: Did you try the solution yourself? You will get the same result. The default comparison compares the reference and two instances have not the same reference

Comment: This doesn't work either, I have overridden the object Equals method and gotten it to work but it puts another ForEach in there which I dont want. I'll try to figure something else out